# Why does the social share buttons look bad?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, autolayout, uikit

### I have defined the news vertically together in stackview. I want to put the share buttons horizontally. I have 5 different share buttons. only 4 of them are visible on the screen and are distorted. How can I fix?

**Here I define stackview and a button. the properties of all buttons are the same.**

```
  private let shareStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .center
        return stackView
    }()
    
    private let facebookShareButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "facebook"), for: .normal)
        button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return button
    }()
```

**I'm making a definition here.**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        scrollView.addSubview(shareStackView)
        stackView.addSubview(navigationBar)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(articleTitleLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(articlePublishedAtLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(articleImageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(articleContentLabel)
        shareStackView.addArrangedSubview(facebookShareButton)
        shareStackView.addArrangedSubview(twitterShareButton)
        shareStackView.addArrangedSubview(instagramShareButton)
        shareStackView.addArrangedSubview(linkedinShareButton)
        shareStackView.addArrangedSubview(emailShareButton) 
    }
```

**This shareStackview position codes **

```
   self.shareStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.shareStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.shareStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.stackView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.shareStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.shareStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.shareStackView.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        
        //constrain width of stack view to width of self.view, NOT scroll view
        self.stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

**This screenshot**

[image]

**here full codes in github**
[enter link description here](https://github.com/bilaldurnagol/NewsApp)

Comment: Have you tried other values for button.contentMode ? If not, try playing with this property

Comment: Try `shareStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing`

Comment: @aheze I did stackView.distribution = .fillEqually . it's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said haw you want them to be positioned so there are two possible solutions I can think of.

---

Space out the images equally

```
stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
```

This will equally space out the images in the stackview based on its width. The images should keep their size.

---

Center the images on screen.

```
    self.shareStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.shareStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.shareStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.stackView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.shareStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.shareStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.shareStackView.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        
    //constrain width of stack view to width of self.view, NOT scroll view
    self.stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

This will change the constraints on the stackView to allow it to be smaller than the width of the screen but stay centered.

Comment: I did stackView.distribution = .fillEqually . it's OK.